# MQTT for GSM/GPRS sheild

Tags: programming

I want to publish sensor data to server using MQTT protocol via GPRS/GSM modem.

I googled MQTT for Arduino, AQTT Arduino available only for Ethernet shield or will MQTT Arduino Ethernet shield work in GSM modem?

Answer (score 1):

Nick O'leary published an MQTT client for Arduino.
I use it extensively.  You can find it here: http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/.
Once you have established a tcpip connection you can use this library to send/receive via the MQTT protocol across a GPRS/GSM modem.  I have used it successfully on:

- the Arduino GSM shield
- the Seeeduino GPRS IoT panel
- a Freetronics Arduino Mega connecting via ethernet to a TPLink MR3020 router

Comment: Do you have an example for the GSM shield?

Answer (score 1):

Arduino MQTT Library for SIM800 (and SIM900) GSM Modem is available at [ElementzTechBlog](https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/arduino-mqtt-library-for-sim800-gsm-modem/), [ElementzGithubRepository](https://github.com/elementzonline/SIM800_MQTT)

**Functionalities:**

**Auto connect**

- Automatically connect to TCP and to MQTT server.

**connect function**

- This function can be used to connect your client to MQTT broker.
- Use only if you do not use Auto connect functionality.
- Optionally  you can use username, password, WILL topic and WILL
  Message.

**OnConnect CallBack function**

- This call back function is called when MQTT connection is
  established.
- You can call subscription and publish functions inside it (according to your need).

**publish function**
 - This function can be used to publish messages to different topics.

- You can select  QoS levels and RETAIN flag according to your need.

**subscribe function**

- This function can be used to subscribe messages from different
  topics.

**OnMessage CallBack function**

- This callback function is called when messages are received from 
  subscribed topics
- Topic, TopicLength, Message, MessageLength are the arguments of 
  OnMessage callback function.
- Inside this, you can write your custom code.

**unsubscribe function**

- This function can be used to unsubscribe from a previously subscribed
  topic.

**disconnect function**

- This function can be used to disconnect your client from MQTT broker.

**Keep Alive**

- You can specify your KeepAlive duration while initializing.
- Ping requests are sent and received automatically.

**Subscribe Publish examples are also provided.**

Answer (score 0):

MQTT is an TCP/IP protocol. MQTT-SN is for wireless serial and is slightly different but you can bridge the two.  Since you can establish a TCP/IP session over GSM, I would expect that functionality would not be duplicated in any way by MQTT, but would instead depend on your GSM hardware providing the TCP layer.

And the final comment, I doubt if you would ever see this on an Arduino. Simple alternative, use a common smartphone as a wifi hot spot, done.

Comment: MQTT is a "light weight" messaging protocol for use **on top** of the TCP/IP protocol.